# ArangoDB: Collect syntax statement error when adding the sum function for an collection attribute

Tags: arangodb, collect

I am trying to add all the Amounts in the edge collection and also extract the days from the date attribute in the edge collection named Transaction.

However, I am getting error in the collect statement.

```
for d in Transaction 
        filter d._to == "Account/123" 
        COLLECT aggregate ct =count(d._id),
        aggregate totamnt=sum(d.Amount), 
        aggregate daysactive= count(distinct date_trunc(d.Time))
return distinct {"Incoming Accounts":length, "Days Active": daysactive}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to achieve correctly, this is a query to achieve it:

```
FOR d IN Transaction
        FILTER d._to == "Account/123" 
        COLLECT AGGREGATE length = COUNT_UNIQUE(d._id), 
                          totamnt = SUM(d.Amount),
                          daysactive = COUNT_UNIQUE(DATE_TRUNC(d.Time, "day"))
        RETURN { 
            "Incoming Accounts": length , 
            "Days Active": LENGTH(daysactive), 
            "Total Amount": totamnt 
        }
```

Note: The `distinct` is not necessary, I include the total amount in the return value, and specified "day" as the unit to truncate the date to.

I tested this slightly adapted on a collection of mine and got sensible results.

Comment: I also had another query.  Here in the above query I had to mention "Account/123" statically in the filter statement. Is there any way where I can do it dynamically which gives the user to input the vertex he wants to?

Comment: Use a placeholder and bind-parameters in your client language; e.g. javascript: `var vertex_id = 'UserInput'; var query = aql\`FOR d IN Transaction FILTER d._to == ${vertex_id} COLLECT...\``; In the Query Webinterface use `d._to == @vertexid`, you get an input-field to the right of the window where you can fill in vertex ids to test this.